# I have 250 windows folders, each of which has 4 zip files within it. How can I use python to extract the contents?

Tags: python, windows

I have 250 windows folders, each of which has 4 zip files within it.

The folders are labeled with a date in the following format "YYYYMMDD".

Each folder then has zip files titled HX.gz where X is a number 1 to 4.

I want to extract all H1.gz files and combine them in a separate folder, but don't want to manually do this 250 times.

How can I use python to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers
site](https://stackoverflow.com/about), not a code-writing service. Please read
through [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your
question to reflect your work.

Comment: can you do one of those folders via python? If not, what is the issue you have doing one folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
# pip install patool
from patool import extract_archive as e
from os import scandir
from os.path import isdir
a,b=['master dir'],0
while b!=len(a):
    for i in scandir(a[b]):
        if isdir(i.path):
            a.append(i.path)
    b+=1
del b
for i in a:
    for j in scandir(i):
        if not isdir(j.path) and (j.path.endswith('.rar') or j.path.endswith('.zip')):
            e(j.path,outdir='your path')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).